# Repeat input type file when user enter number

Tags: angular, angular6

If user enter integer inside textbox eg:3 then the file uploader will display 3 time
i am start learning  angular so it will be great if some give me solution.
here is link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7x61y2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see forked [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xu63op?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).